# Cannot WOL dual-booted PC - Firewall?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, ip-address

I cannot figure this out; I swear I am doing everything correctly:

In BIOS:

- Wake from Onboard LAN -> Enabled

In windows:

- I have enabled every capable NIC to Wake on LAN (Magic Packet)
- I have checked all the boxes under the Power Management Tab for the same NIC's ^ and not allowed the computer to power them off

In ubuntu:

`ethtool` output:

```
ethtool enp0s31f6
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Why cant my computer WOL... I cant figure it out

EDIT:
I’m starting to wonder if maybe there is some issue with my network infrastructure like a firewall or something?
Is this true - https://forums.techguy.org/threads/not-allowed-to-to-set-up-wake-on-lan-on-a-xfinity-modem.1201350/ ?

Comment: Do you have [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#networking) installed?

Comment: Nope, never heard of it till now, I guess it’s like power management under windows? Do you think that’s my problem?

Comment: Yes, it's mainly for notebooks. Once installed, it disables WOL by default, I guess. See the link above. So I don't think that is your problem.

Comment: Darn... you think maybe it’s installed in Ubuntu by default? I can check later today

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. After reading every forum post on WOL that every existed and spending hours on this:

- I determined that packet was being sent via Wireshark
- I needed to know if NIC was still on even though the computer was off... Pretty orange light when on; nothing when off
- Decided it was probably something in the BIOS... Went through EVERY menu option and found whole 'nother page of settings that I wouldnt've have thought to look for. Found what I needed in there.

To anyone with a similar problem:

- Make sure packet is broadcasted
- Go through all settings in your BIOS just to be sure